# Removing from and Shuffling a C++ vector

Tags: visual-c++, vector, stl, shuffle, erase

I am using a vector to represent a deck of cards in c++. I am having trouble shuffling the deck and removing the first element.

Shuffling does not work, the vector keeps the same order. I call reseed once in my program, in the constructor of Deck. int random is different every time. I have tried time(NULL) and time(0). Shuffling:

```
void Deck::reseed() {
srand(time(NULL));
}

void Deck::shuffle() {
int random = rand();
for(int i = 0; i < random; i++) {
    std::random_shuffle(deckVec.begin(), deckVec.end());
}
}
```

Removing does not work, the last element is removed instead of the first (for example, element 16 is erased and not element 0). Removing:

```
Card Deck::dealCard() {
//other code...
Card& tempCard = deckVec.front();
std::vector<Card>::iterator temp = deckVec.begin(); //This if for debugging, and 
                                                    //this pointer is correct   
deckVec.erase(deckVec.begin()); 
return tempCard; //the correct card is returned
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

-----------Update----------------
code for printing before and after shuffle:

```
cout << deck.toString(); //output: Suit: Clubs, Rank: 2
                         //        Suit: Clubs, Rank: 3 ...   
//shuffle if there are three arguments
if(argc == 3)
   deck.shuffle();
cout << deck.toString();//output: Suit: Clubs, Rank: 2
                        //        Suit: Clubs, Rank: 3 ... (identical to above)
```

It's difficult to show dealCard. Basically, I call it here:

```
void operator<<(Hand& hand, Deck& deck) {
    hand.addCard(deck.dealCard());
}
```

Then I print out the contents. The output is: C2 C2 C2 C2 ... for the 2 of Clubs. They are all the first card in the deck.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for(unsigned int j = 0; j < hands.size(); j++) {
                try {
                hands.at(j) << deck;
                } catch(int& i) {
                    cout << "no cards left" << endl;
                }
            }
        }

        //print out the contents
        cout << deck.toString() << endl;
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < hands.size(); i++) {
            cout << "Hand " << i << ": ";
            cout << hands.at(i).toString() << endl;
        }
```

Comment: How do you determine that these two methods "don't work"? What evidence do you have of this?

Comment: A combination of stepping through with the debugger and printing the contents out to the console.

Comment: Show the code that prints to the console, what the output is, and explain why do you believe this output is incorrect.

Comment: Would you like to know anything else? Is that clearer?

Comment: You need to create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). There are too many unknowns in your code. What's the relationship between `deck` and `deckVec`, what does `Deck::toString` do, is `argc` in fact equal to 3, what's `Card`, what does its copy constructor and assignment operator look like, why are you trying to catch an exception when `dealCard` doesn't throw any? For what it's worth, I don't see anything wrong with your `shuffle` and `dealCard` implementations (except that calling `random_shuffle` more than once doesn't in fact make the order any more random). The problem likely lies elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. I'll keep looking into it. Should I post a zip with the relevant code? It should be a little less than 20 kb.

Comment: Ah, I take this back. `dealCard` is wrong. `tempCard` is a reference to the first element - the very element you erase on the next line, at which point `tempCard` becomes a dangling reference. This code exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: That makes sense. I changed tempCard to a Card and no longer a Card&. It still erases the last element in deckVec. I am assuming the last element in deckVec is the one with the largest index when I use the debugger. I get the two of clubs every time.

Comment: Do you know what operators erase and begin use?

Comment: With all due respect, I'm not interested in reviewing 20K worth of someone else's code - not unless I'm compensated for my troubles. No, the burden is on you to reduce your problem down to a size that someone would be willing to look at on a lazy Saturday's evening. Something [along these lines](http://ideone.com/5DOEFB) (which, by the way, resembles your code rather closely, and produces an expected output).

Comment: "Do you know what operators erase and begin use?" I don't understand the question. The same operators that any other code uses, I suppose. Why does it matter?

Comment: I recommend you to use `std::shuffle` if you are using a compiler with c++11 support. It uses uniform random distribution and engines from random header. It doesn't depend on global state from `rand()`. Besides that, there are proposals in c++14 to deprecate `rand()` and friends.

Comment: Hi all. Thank you guys so much for the help. I finally solved the problem. My operator= for my card struct returned a const Card (the compiler was yelling at me earlier to make one with a const Card return type). However, I went back fixed this problem and replaced it with a return type of Card&. Everything was fixed.